# Get all users how have multiple roles of certain type of roles

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a user_roles table in which the user can have more than one active role from one type (RoleID) but in more than one region (RegionID) as in the sql table code, i want to get all the users who have more than one active role in more than one type.

table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRole](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL )
```

[image]

Comment: Nothing in your table is called "type", so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: By "Type", do you mean Region?

Comment: type is the Role Id in the table

Comment: I updated my question